# How to avoid overloading Main_activity OnCreate with @Overloads?

Tags: android, android-activity

I would like to minimize the bloat in Main_Activity made necessary by so many @Overload sections.  My Windows experience makes me think of moving as much as possible to the individual Classes, but in Android, it seems to be unavailable.  All these accesses to the system, do they all have to be anchored in Main_Activity?

Examples I'm using and would like to add:

1. rotation = display.getRotation(); followed by sections designing Portrait and then Landscape
2. Within each of those, a setOnClickListener(View) to resist keyboard popup when user so chooses (until needed)
3. addTextChangedListener followed by beforeTextChanged, onTextChanged, and afterTextChanged.
4. onPrepareOptionsMenu, to control that cussed thing popping up and blocking my way (until needed of course, optionalizing its moment of appearance)
5. startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a file"

These are working OK (all but one so far) but so cluttered. Many other system functions one should think were one's right to use, but if only one could distribute the clutter out of Main_Activity into each of what would be relevant classes.

Am I trying to fit Android into a Windows mindset, and is this unavoidable, or is there some happy door I can open to relieve the pressure?

Thanks for any suggestions in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Android components should strictly be kept within the Activity (View). Methods like `onPrepareOptionsMenu` could reside in a BaseActivity that your activities extend from as presumably each of your activities will share the same menu? And if not then said activity can override it.

As for too much logic in the Activity, employ a pattern, [Model View Presenter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter) is generally a good all-rounder in mobile app design at spreading the load between classes.

There's nothing wrong with getting creative and creating a ViewUpdater class (for example), returning a view for landscape and portrait to your activity when called...

Comment: This looks like a very good answer, JakeB.  But it will take me some days to get the drift on its operations.  Many thanks.  I'm feeling optimistic.